# Jquery plugin for searchable dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to jquery. I am trying to design a drop down list that includes a search filter. In deep, i have a left side navigation bar. When i click on the nav field, a drop down list is displayed. Below the list a search field too. When i type any of the drop down entry and click enter, it is redirected to the corresponding page. I have seen many jquery plugins. But not sure how to make use of it. Anyone give me a vague idea about how this works? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to have a look at https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: maybe something like this https://select2.github.io/examples.html ?

Comment: Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 1):

[Select 2](https://select2.github.io/examples.html) is very practical as it offers multi-select lists as dropdown with a built in search function

Comment: Refered select2. Tutorial is fantastic, But the problem is my dropdown is of ul li instead of select tag. Can i have any links that shows search filter in dropdown using ul li